# Nullable nonterminals

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory

I have to find out if a given grammar contains the null string ( epsilon) using a programming language not pen and paper.
The thing is everywhere I look I find this:
 if  A→ϵ is a production, A is nullable.
if A→X1X2…Xn  is a production, and X1,X2,…,XnX1,X2,…,Xn are all nullable, then A is nullable.

The problem is that I dont have something like Xn->ϵ. I have something like
A->BCA|BC
B->C|A
C->BB|AA

Comment: Are there any terminals?

Comment: the grammar is as you see. A,B, and C are nonterminals and even if there are some terminals they are unreachable given the grammar

Comment: In that case, the language contains no strings at all, which is not the same as containing the empty string. Perhaps that is the distinction your assignment is trying to get you to recognize.